# content of dhcp lease-query message

Tags: dhcpv6

Does the DHCPv6 LEASEQUERY-REPLY message contain the DUID (or MAC) of the client whose information we are requesting from the server?

Comment: Did any answer help you? if so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like it carries the DUID.

**From - [RFC 5007 Section 4.3.3](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5007#section-4.3.3)**

```
4.3.3.  Receipt of LEASEQUERY-REPLY

   A successful LEASEQUERY-REPLY is one without an OPTION_STATUS_CODE
   option (or an OPTION_STATUS_CODE option with a success code).  There
   are three variants:

   1.  If the server had bindings for the requested client, the message
       includes an OPTION_CLIENT_DATA option and the requestor extracts
       the client data from the LEASEQUERY-REPLY and updates its binding
       information database.  If the OPTION_CLIENT_DATA contains no
       OPTION_CLT_TIME, the requestor SHOULD silently discard the
       OPTION_CLIENT_DATA option.
```

**If we look at the details of how "OPTION_CLIENT_DATA" is constructed in [RFC 5007 Section 4.4.2](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5007#section-4.4.2)**

```
4.4.2.  Constructing the Client's OPTION_CLIENT_DATA

   An OPTION_CLIENT_DATA option in a LEASEQUERY-REPLY message MUST
   minimally contain the following options:
   1.  OPTION_CLIENTID
   2.  OPTION_IAADDR and/or OPTION_IAPREFIX
   3.  OPTION_CLT_TIME
```

**Now we can look at the details of "OPTION_CLIENTID" in [RFC 3315 Section 22.2](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3315#section-22.2)**

```
22.2. Client Identifier Option

   The Client Identifier option is used to carry a DUID (see section 9)
   identifying a client between a client and a server.  The format of
   the Client Identifier option is:

       0                   1                   2                   3
       0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 1
      +-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
      |        OPTION_CLIENTID        |          option-len           |
      +-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
      .                                                               .
      .                              DUID                             .
      .                        (variable length)                      .
      .                                                               .
      +-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+

      option-code   OPTION_CLIENTID (1).

      option-len    Length of DUID in octets.
```